# How to automatically transfer specific fields in another excel sheet?

Tags: database, excel

I have an excel sheet containing some data, i.e. main sheet. How can I automatically transfer the fields that contains the same value for a specific column, i.e. here A, in the main sheet to another sheet. 
Please take a look at this example:
this the main sheet:

```
   A       B     C     D   
1  Smith   100   Mar   1
2  Bob     95    Apr   5 
3  John    34    Aug   4 
4  Bob     88    mar   7 
5  John     7    Apr   4
```

Let's say column A is the reference column   for sorting. We want all fields containing the same value in A to move to a separated sheet. The same for other duplicate values of A is also expected.

The result should be :

```
Sheet 1:
       A       B     C     D   
    1  Bob     95    Apr   5
    2  Bob     88    mar   7 


Sheet 2:
       A       B     C     D   
    1  John    34    Aug   4 
    2  John     7    Apr   4

Sheet 3:
       A       B     C     D   
    1  Smith   100   Mar   1
```

If possible I want this method to be up-to-date, as if a row is removed in the main sheet, the change applies in the corresponding sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1) duplicate the data in the sheets with sheet2(cell) = sheet1(cell) references for each  sheet. Then having a filter on for each new sheet for column as wanted value.
2) write a VB script, possible triggered by the worksheets(main data) onChange function monitoring that data range, and copying the rowns to new WSs.

3) make a new pivot table for each "additional" sheet where you can configure the data you want to show

implementation kinda depends on if you want to keep the data "up to date" like if there is a row deletion in main data should it be removed from other sheets etc. but simple one time copy would be code like(not actual syntax but just pseudocode):

sub Worksheet_Change(range)

if range in wnated range

copy entire row from sheet (data) to sheet X (sheet X will be chosen depending on value of column A)